# CSS - Animation whole ul and not just first row when new item enters

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

Take a look at [this simple JsFiddle I made](http://jsfiddle.net/y30cmnqz/73/) which is animating new items that enter the list.

However, the animation only affects for the first row, and not for all of the rows.
I made the colors random, so you can actually see the "jumps" on the other rows, when a new item is being inserted.

Is there a way to make it it affect all rows just with CSS?

```
@keyframes enter {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    margin-left: calc(var(--w) * -1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    margin-left: 0
  }
}
```

This is my animation, and this is my list item:

```
.slidepush li {
  --w: 50px;
  width: var(--w);
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: top;


  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.enter {
  animation: enter 1s;
}
```

Ceated a simple class that manages the ul and implements add:

```
class SlidePush {

    constructor(ulElement) {
    this.element = ulElement;
  }

  add(item) {
    this.element.prepend(item.addClass('enter'));
  }
}

const sp = new SlidePush($(".slidepush"));

setInterval(() => {//
  var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black'];
  var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  sp.add($("<li style='background-color:" + color +" !important;'></li>"));
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add the animation considering `nth-child` so you add to always the first one on each row. You need to also remove the animation after it's done to be able to add it again to the same element when it reach the next row.

```js
class SlidePush {

 constructor(ulElement) {
   this.element = ulElement;
  }
  
  add(item) {
   this.element.prepend(item);
    $('.slidepush li:nth-child(4n+1)').addClass('enter');
    setTimeout(function(){ $('.slidepush li:nth-child(4n+1)').removeClass('enter') }, 1000);
  }
}

const sp = new SlidePush($(".slidepush"));

setInterval(() => {//
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black'];
var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
sp.add($("<li style='background-color:" + color +" !important;'></li>"));
}, 1200);
```

```css
div {
--w: 200px;
  max-width: var(--w);
}


.slidepush {
  list-style: none;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: table;
  }

.slidepush li {
  --w: 50px;
  width: var(--w);
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: top;

  
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
      
.enter {
  animation: enter 1s;
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
}
      
@keyframes enter {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    margin-left: calc(var(--w) * -1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="slidepush">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it has random jumps, it's not smooth, and it only works for a fixed width (e.g 200px).

Comment: @Jony Well, I tried a lot of ways and it's not easy .. have you something in mind for the animation? if you can do a static example of how you want it to look it may help

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following code.

```js
class SlidePush {

  constructor(ulElement) {
    this.element = ulElement;
  }

  add(item) {
    $('.slidepush li').removeClass('enter');
    $('.slidepush li').removeClass('push');
    $('.slidepush li:nth-child(4n+1)').addClass('push');
    this.element.prepend(item.addClass('enter'));
  }
}

const sp = new SlidePush($(".slidepush"));

setInterval(() => { //
  var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black'];
  var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  sp.add($("<li style='background-color:" + color + " !important;'></li>"));
}, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  --w: 200px;
  max-width: var(--w);
}

.slidepush {
  list-style: none;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: table;
}

.slidepush li {
  --w: 50px;
  width: var(--w);
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.enter {
  animation-name: enter;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.push {
  animation-name: push;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes push {
  0% {
    margin-left: calc(var(--w) * -1);
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0
  }
}

@keyframes enter {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="slidepush">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Again, it's not smooth, it bugs out a bit every time an item is inserted